# How do I use the value of a cell when I know the id of a row?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms

I have an `int` value `h`, and I want to search in the database (column `id`) for the `h` value. When I get the row, I want just a particular cell that represents the price, and I want to use it later in the code. So if a player has money and wants to buy the thing with the `h` id, the value of the thing is subtracted from the sum of money.

So how do I get the price and use it? I know what I did here isn't good.

```
void TitluCasuta(int h)
{
  deschideconexiunea();
  string s = "SELECT Titlu FROM TitluriProprietate WHERE id=h";
  cmd = new SqlCeCommand(s, con);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You hard-coded "h" into your query. It's not using your value at all. Read up on using [`parameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.parameters(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
string query = "SELECT Titlu FROM TitluriProprietate WHERE id = @id";

using (var cmd = new SqlCeCommand(query, con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int, h));

    return Convert.ToDecimal(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

Comment: Hey! I triede something like this  void AfisareCasuta(int h)
       {
           afisare(@"SELECT Titlu, Pret
                   FROM TitluriProprietate
                   WHERE ID=@Id");
          
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int, h));
       }'

Comment: Sorry, and afisare is a function that does something like this:

Comment: deschideconexiunea();
            cmd = new SqlCeCommand(s, con);
            da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);
            dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();

Comment: i want to show in the data grid view the row with the id=h; Thank you for your help!!